# How to untrigger a function if the length of input is less than 3?

Tags: reactjs, redux, autocomplete

I'm relatively new to react and redux. I fired an autocomplete function when the length of the input is > 3 but when i hit backspace, the suggestions still show as there is change. How can I prevent this from happening?

````
    if(e.target.value.length>3)
      //fire function
   }
   render()
    return(
     {this.props.value.map(x => <li>
       {x}</li>}
      )```
````

Comment: We'll need to know a lot more about how the code works than a comment. Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit too vague.. I think you are referring to preventDefault()

```
autoComplete(e){
if(e.target.value.length>3){
   getAutoCompleteSuggestions()
}
else{
 e.preventDefault();
 }
}

render(){
return(
<input onChange={this.autoComplete} value={this.state.inputValue}/>
}
```